# YES is false in if statement?

Tags: cmake

Following lines generates `false YES` message in CMake. Why?

```
set(A "YES")

if(${A})
  message("true " ${A})
else()
  message("false " ${A})
endif()
```

Comment: For me it prints `true YES`. Probably, there is variable named `YES` somewhere in your code. Note, that proper check for variable's value is to **not dereference** the variable: `if(A)`. See how variables are expanded in `if` command: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#variable-expansion

Comment: Your code snippet is missing `cmake_minimum_required`... this is _**HUGELY**_ important!!! See, for instance, [CMP0054](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0054.html)